# Как интегрировать 1С с интернет-магазином?

Tags: 1с

Опишите, пожалуйста, как обычно объединяют 1С в офисе с интернет-магазином, находящимися на удалённом хостинге, причем, в обе стороны: каталог товаров, цены и кол-во на складе обновляется из 1С, а заказы поступают из магазина.

Только вручную? Свистопляска с батниками, расписанием и переброской CSV-файлов?

Comment: Мне понравилась Ваша формулировка вопроса - Вы, наверное, книги писали когда-то. Я загуглил "Как интегрировать 1С с интернет-магазином", и третья ссылка - 1С-Битрикс.
http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/cms/1c/
 + книга есть еще, тоже от 1С,названия не помню, к сожалению.

Comment: @sergiks, судя по комментарию, отсылающему в гугл и 2-м минусам основные (в последнее время) посетители форума **ничего по сути** Вашего вопроса не знают.

Comment: извините, очень долго писал )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Существует решение из коробки для битрикса. Смысл заключается в формировании CommerceML файлов для каталога товаров, их свойств, цен и остатков. Поддерживается как полная загрузка каталога, так и формирование файлов изменений, регистрируемых в плане обмена с сайтом. Загружаются также и заказы... В битриксе соответственно существует загрузка этих данных. [Протокол обмена с сайтом](http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/131/). Безотносительно битрикса и его чудовищности, механизм этот практически самостоятельный, во всяком случае ознакомиться с ним не помешает (если есть такая возможность).

Есть сторонние проприетарные разработки для связи с проприетарными же движками сайтов, гугль про них знает, если что.

Все зависит, конечно, от того насколько тесная интеграция реализуется, но в любом случае не повредит узнать, что связывая 1С и сайт придется столкнуться со следующими проблемами:

- Несоответствие каталога товаров на сайте со структурой номенклатуры в 1С. Не удивительно, т.к. в 1С работают продавцы, менеджеры, на сайт приходят посетители. Структура каталогов почти наверное не совпадает.

Некоторые пытаются преобразовать номенклатуру к виду на сайте, но обычно это fail. Отсюда возникает необходимость в дополнительных структурах (читай доработка конфигурации в большинстве случаев с нуля и не универсальная), отчасти дублирующих существующие данные, которые приводят к довольно большому объему работы менеджеров контента.

В частности, при добавлении новой номенклатуры необходимо добавлять эту номенклатуру на сайт в нужную группу, задавать необходимые свойства и т.д. Проблема в том, что в большинстве случаев за структуру Номенклатуры в 1С отвечает один человек, за структуру каталога на сайте совсем другие люди.

- Вторая проблема - это объем информации для синхронизации с сайтом. Есть два варианта - вести каталог в 1С и вести каталог на сайте, в админке (имеется в виду свойства, картинки, характеристики товаров, которых просто может не быть в 1С по причине отсутствия надобности в учете). Первый вариант позволяет больше возможностей с точки зрения простоты и часто скорости ввода. Второй вариант позволяет избавиться от необходимости синхронизации каталога на каждое изменение не только структуры, но и свойств, категорий и т.д. Какой из вариантов выбирать зависит от каталога и размера номенклатуры.

Если для ведения каталога все-таки использовать 1С, то отсюда будет вытекать и метод выгрузки. Скажем csv хорош для простых списков, если же по каждому товару будет довольно много дополнительной информации, то XML выглядит предпочтительнее (как вариант CommerceML, не лишенный недостатков, но свою работу выполняющий). Также надо учитывать, что при большом объеме нужно будет дробить файлы на части и обрабатывать по частям (иначе timeout'ы на сервере и полный провал с выгрузкой).

- Следующий момент, частота обновлений как в одну сторону (каталог, цены, свойства...) так и в другую (заказы покупателей).

Если цены меняются на весь каталог ежедневно, то выгрузка данных может занимать довольно большое время и встанет задача минимизации отправляемых данных. Изменение цен с точки зрения 1С не просто изменение одной цифры на другую, например, с точки зрения сайта может поменяться не только цена но и товар - добавили характеристики, товар уже другой, и цена соответственно тоже.

При загрузке заказов покупателей придется реализовывать логику мгновенного обновления статуса (а может быть и состава заказа) в зависимости действий менеджера. Особенно если заказы обрабатывает сразу несколько человек. Неплохим вариантом здесь может стать веб-сервис...

Если идти от простого к сложному длинным путем, то да, берем каталог выгружаем в csv, смотрим на результат - на 95% не устраивает. Дальше появляется вуду...

Comment: Спасибо, что поделились столь подробно ценным опытом!

Comment: Не за что. Просто для одних людей сайт основная торговая площадка, для других дополнение к оффлайну. В зависимости от безбашенности и богатости клиента могут быть разные требования и как следствие положительный или отрицательный эффект от такой интеграции.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю к описанному еще один вариант интеграции 1С и интернет-магазина. Он сложнее стандартного обмена 1С, но потенциал решения намного выше. По сути, получается полноценный бэкенд, практически не требующий захода в административную часть интернет-магазина.

---

- В 1С реализуется подсистема (конфигурация с поддержки не снимается), которая:

  - "знает" данные 1С и может напрямую к ним обращаться;
  - "знает" структуру таблиц базы данных интернет магазина.

Наличие доступа к обеим сторонам обмена (1с и интернет-магазин) позволяет настроить полноценное и однозначное соответствие данных, а также задавать правила обмена, в т.ч. двусторонние.
Разумеется, возникает избыточность данных - подсистема дублирует в себя справочник Номенклатура, неизбежное следствие требования оставить конфигурацию на сопровождении. Взамен получаем возможность в 1С видеть и работать с товарами в той иерархии, которая используется на сайте. А для складского учета - продолжать использовать стандартный справочник 1С номенклатуры с привычной иерархией.

Основное отличие такой архитектуры - устраняется узкое место - конвертация данных при подготовке к передаче и получении с сайта. Поскольку сопоставление данных явно настраивается, никаких случайных рассинхронизаций (и задвоений) не происходит. Отлаживать такой обмен гораздо проще. Особенно хорошо это работает, если при передаче данных используется обращение к API движка магазина. Побочный бонус - очень высокая скорость обмена, так как избыточность данных - минимальна.